# What is the story of Amruth Manthan?

Tags: samudra-manthan

I heard Amruth Manthan today. I do not know what it means. Can anyone explain me the story of Amruth Manthan?

Answer (score 1):

**Samudra Manhan** :

- Mrut  = Dead
- Amrut ( Amrit ) = A liquid which can give immortality to anyone (Elixir of life).
- Manthan = to churn

Once Devtas & Asuras came togather to get Amrut by doing Samudra Manthan ( Churning of The Ocean ). They come down to ocean of milk and took the mountain Mandara as a churning-pole and the hundred-headed serpent Vāsuki as a churning-rope. They tied the serpent around the mountain, and started churning the ocean.

They churned the Ocean of milk for thousand years and many things came out from the ocean. The Lord Dhanvantary ( the heavenly physician ) appeared with pot containing Amrut inside it. Vishnu took the Mohini avatar and distracted the Asuras from drinking the Amrut.

Then lord Vishnu distributed the Amrut among devtas but one of the Asura that is RahuKetu took the avatar of a devta. Later on when Vishnu came to know about this, he threw his divine weapon Sudarshana, which cuts off RahuKetu's head, but the nectar had reached upto his throat so he did not died.

Hence, his head and body were then separated, and later on they became planets, i.e Rahu and Ketu.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan)